Laravel 11 | window.echo not listening event for private channel
hello i have developed a chat App, and laravel echo not listening the event.
Event class
<?php
namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Message;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        \Log::info('Event fired: ', $message->toArray());
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('conversation.' . $this->message->conversation_id);
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'message.sent';
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['message' => $this->message->load('sender')];
    }
}

message sent method in cpontroller
 public function sendMessage(Request $request)
    {
        $find = Conversation::where('id', $request->input('conversation_id'))->get();
        if (count($find)) {
            $conversation = Conversation::where('id', $request->input('conversation_id'))->first();
            $conversation->title = substr($request->input('content'), 0, 25);
            $conversation->save();
        }

        $message = new Message();
        $message->conversation_id = $request->input('conversation_id');
        $message->user_id = auth()->id();
        $message->content = $request->input('content');
        $message->save();

        broadcast(new MessageSent($message))->toOthers();

        return response()->json(['status' => 'Message sent!']);
    }

channels.php
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use App\Models\Conversation;

Broadcast::channel('conversation.{conversationId}', function ($user, $conversationId) {
    return Conversation::where('id', $conversationId)
                        ->where(function ($query) use ($user) {
                            $query->where('sender_id', $user->id)
                                  ->orWhere('receiver_id', $user->id);
                    })->exists();
});

Pusher integration for real-time updates
in a vue component i am calling this pusher method when i need to send message for generate real time notification. for receiver in chat app
const setupPusher = (conversationId) => {
    console.log('Setting up pusher for conversation');
    if (window.Echo && conversationId) {
        console.log(window.Echo);
        console.log(conversationId);
        console.log('Listening for messages on conversation');
        window.Echo.private(`conversation.${conversationId}`)
            .listen('.message.sent', (e) => {
                console.log('Event received:', e);
                messages.value.push(e.message);
            });
    }
};

